# How can I get all the property names from a javascript object literal that contains nested objects?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

For example, if I have this javascript object literal:

```
var foo = {
    a: '1',
    b: {
        doit: function toit(){},
        c: true,
        d: {
          x: true,
          y: true
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get an array of all the property names? Such as:

```
['a', 'b', 'doit', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y']
```

Comment: For in loops would be perfect for this.  Here is a link about them http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursive function

```
function recursiveKeyFinder(object, result) {
    for (var key in object) {
        result.push(key);
        if (Object(object[key]).toString() === "[object Object]") {
            recursiveKeyFinder(object[key], result);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(recursiveKeyFinder(foo, []));
# [ 'a', 'b', 'doit', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all the properties using the for in loop and push them to an array.

```
> 
for (var key in foo) {
   var obj = foo[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      // important check that this is objects own property 
      // not from prototype prop inherited
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        arr.push(prop);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Recursive function )

```
var foo = {
    a: '1',
    b: {
        doit: function toit(){},
        c: true,
        d: {
          x: true,
          y: true
        }
    }
};

var getKeys = function ( foo ) {
    var bar = [];

    for ( var key in foo ) {
        var _foo = foo [ key ];
        bar.push ( key );
        if ( typeof _foo === 'object') {
            var _bar = getKeys ( foo [key] );
            for (var _key in _bar ) {
                bar.push ( _bar[_key] );
            }

        }
    }

    return bar;
};


var bar = getKeys ( foo );

alert ( bar );
```

Demo Here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t73qy/)

Answer (score 0):

A function such as this would do the job:

```
function getKeysRecursive(obj)
{
  var keys = [];

  (function r(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      keys.push(key);
      if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {
        r(obj[key]);
      }
    });
  }(obj));

  return keys;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qumiduda/1/)